# Defining a function to a subset of the codomain

Tags: functional-programming, lean

I am trying to define the image restriction of a function
f : A → B    as    f': A → f[A], where    f'(a) = f(a)    . However, I am not sure how to define it in a lean.
In my opinion, the most intuitive way to define it is:

```
def fun_to_image {A B: Type*} (f: A → B): A → image f set.univ :=
        λ a, f a
```

However, this gets rejected because (f a) is of type B not (image f set.univ).

I even tried proving that    f(a) ∈ (image f univ)    . It didn't help:

```
def fun_to_image (f : A → B) : A → image f univ := 
    λ a , 
    have h : f a ∈ image f univ := 
        exists.intro a 
            (and.intro trivial (eq.refl (f a))),
    f a
```

The error message is:

```
type mismatch, term
  λ (a : A), f a
has type
  A → B
but is expected to have type
  A → ↥(f '' univ)
```

set.univ and image are defined as follows in data.set

```
def univ : set α :=
λ a, true

def image (f : α → β) (s : set α) : set β :=
{b | ∃ a, a ∈ s ∧ f a = b}
```

Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there (-;

There is a little “warning sign” in the error message.

```
but is expected to have type
  A → ↥(f '' univ)
```

You can see the creepy up-arrow `↥`. Let me explain what it means:

As you have recalled, `image f set.univ` is defined as a subset. Since you are treating it as a type, it is automatically coerced into a so-called subtype: if `s : set X`, then the corresponding `subtype s` has terms of the form `⟨x, h⟩` (type these as `\<` and `\>` in VScode), where `x : X` and `h : x ∈ s`.

This “coercion to type” is indicated by the `↥`.

So, to finish your definition, you will have to write `⟨f a, h⟩`, instead of `f a`.

---

Note that in [main library](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib) there is also a definition of `range` ([here](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/blob/34d69b5054549f6cc2de9a6311be5cba9c595977/src/data/set/basic.lean#L1075)) which is meant to be used in place of `image _ set.univ`.
It already comes with ([L1167](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/blob/34d69b5054549f6cc2de9a6311be5cba9c595977/src/data/set/basic.lean#L1167))

```
def range_factorization (f : ι → β) : ι → range f :=
λ i, ⟨f i, mem_range_self i⟩
```

Comment: Thank you, that really helped and it answers a lot of questions!